# GLUT в XCode 4.6 OpenGL C++ (MacOS X)

Tags: c++, opengl

Всем привет !
Как подключаюстя библиотеки ?
Как работать с проектом(какой нибудь простой пример, чтобы мог на основе него свой наработки наложить)?
Ранее все делал в MVS 2010 C++ , там было все гораздо проще и примеров было много )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замечательные примеры от Нейта Робинса, в том числе для Mac OS, используя Xcode. В них используется glut. http://user.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался как что делается )